# Error: FASTA file not found using building kallisto index

Tags: kallisto

I am trying to build an index on kallisto on mac using R studio and have saved my FASTA file to my desktop, however, when I run `kallisto index -i DI_mRNA.index DI_mRNA.fa.gz`, there is an error saying `Error: FASTA file not found DI_mRNA.fa.gz`

Comment: In what way are you running Kallisto on R?  

My guess would be you are not in the same directory as the fastq file. You can find out the current working directory with ```getwd()``` and set it with ```setwd()```.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment, your working directory lacks the fasta file.